# Fast and accurate LAN host discovery on Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking, arp

I am building a port scanner for Android and am trying out different methods for host discovery. I tried out multithreading ICMP echo requests and found it to be inaccurate since a good amount of newer operating systems block ICMP echo requests by default. I moved on to implementing a mDNS solution and found that to be more accurate but much slower.

What I have settled on for now is reading the ARP table (/proc/net/arp) after it has been populated by parsing the data and looking for IP addresses that have a non-zeroed MAC address. I am filling up the ARP table by multithreading a bunch of calls to [isReachable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int)). I found that I am able to get away with a 1ms timeout in the call to isReachable since I am only using it to fill the ARP table and not actually connect to a host. This has allowed my host discovery to only take a few seconds.

Accuracy and speed are equally as important to me in this process so my question is how stable of a solution is this? Do all Android devices have their ARP table in the same location? Are there any caveats I need to watch out for?

Comment: Just implement Bonjour/Rendezvous.  Perhaps you can use http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmdns/ for it.

Comment: I actually tried out JmDNS specifically and found it to be much slower than this method. Unless I'd gain additional accuracy I'd rather not use something that takes longer than 1 or 2 seconds.

Comment: Properly implemented Bonjour events should trickle in immediately.

Comment: I'll have to revisit it and see if I was doing something wrong...